# JSF 2.2.6 Ajax Partial Rerendering is very slow

Tags: jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

I have created an app using JSF Mojarra 2.2.6, Richfaces 4.x and Seam 2.3.1 on jboss widlfly.

Some of the pages are pretty heavy component wise and it takes average `12s to 15s` for `AJAX partial re-rendering with WELD enabled`.

I have tried all the typical improvements suggested for richfaces and jsf by changing `context-params in web.xml` but none of them have been effective.

Please suggest me a way to improve JSF partial re-rendering of the components on the page as it is taking too much time.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: It would be good if you can post the code which you have tried for the `AJAX partial re-rendering with WELD enabled`

Comment: use a phaselistener to see where the delay is, and read some documentation on the usage of the execute attribute to prevent things being processed on the server.